# jQuery modal not appearing, getting "Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

[JS Fiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/k4hwq7vL/2/)

Code in question:

```
$('#infoTable').click(infoModal);

function infoModal(){
    var table = "THIS IS A TABLE";
    $("#dialogContainer").dialog({
        appendTo: "#msg-dialog",
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            close: { text: 'Close', click: function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    console.log("Thanks for using this!");
                }
            }
        }
    });
    //Append table variable to dialog box
    $('#msg-dialog').after(table);
}
```

I'm new to using the jQueryUI dialog feature, and I think my approach is wrong here. I'm just trying to get the dialog box to show up, but all I get is the `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent` error. As far as I know, the child div element (#msg-dialog) is contained inside the `#dialogContainer` div, not the other way around. Is there something I need to add/remove to get this working?

Comment: `appendTo: "#msg-dialog"` does what?

Comment: Yes, `msg-dialog` is inside `dialogContainer`, which is why you're not allowed to put `dialogContainer` into its own child, or you'd get a loop in the hierarchy.

Comment: [The official jQueryUI API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) says that appendTo places the actual dialog into a specified element.

Comment: Yes, and you specified *one of its own children* as a container.

Comment: Yep, exactly, and `#msg-dialog` is within `#dialogContainer`, which is the actual dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
appendTo: "#msg-dialog",
```

The point here is that `#msg-dialog` *is* **inside** `#dialogContainer`, and you create a dialog on the latter div and append to the former which is a child of the latter.

A quick look at the API documentation will clarify things:

> appendTo
>
> Type: Selector Default: "body" Which element the dialog (and overlay,
>   if modal) should be appended to.
>
> Source: [jqueryUI](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo)

Solution is to take the `msg-dialog` div out of the `dialogContainer` - see [UPDATED FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/k4hwq7vL/3/)

Comment: Got it, so what I need to do is create a specific div to append to, and not that div's parent. This definitely helps, thanks!

Comment: cool, if you leave out the `appendTo` parameter, it will append to the `body` element...